# htaccess 301 redirect takes to wrong URL - misplaced slash

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have to recently redirect a site, say Site A to Site B. It should be per page redirection. The site holds top page ranks in related keywords and I am already worried about it.

Since I have done .htaccess redirects in past, it was not a problem in beginning. But now I am facing horror. Searching online took me to only one thread with similar problem and it went unsolved!

The problem is - after editing redirection in .htaccess in following format:

```
Redirect 301 /url1.html http://siteB.com/url1.html
```

After going to `siteA.com/url1.html`, user is taken to `siteB.com/url1.html/`

This obviously leads to an error. But I do not know what to even search for this problem. It will be a huge loss if I loose ranks here. The site root redirects fine to new site's root.

I hope someone has a solution for it.

Thanks guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the 'obvious' error, other than that you'd have to write a rule for every url used. Better to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newdomain.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Chris, Also remember that siteB might itself have its own rewrite rules and does a 301 from url1.html to url1.html/

Answer (score 0):

Not a big .htaccess expert here, but my site's .htaccess has all the URLs on the right-hand side in double quotes. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this problem and it's because I added `Redirect 301 / http://siteB.com/` at the top.  This redirects every link from siteA to siteB.com, regardless of any other redirects below it.